# programmatically changing Combobox selection without causing the SelectedIndexChanged to fire

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2005

So I have a combobox with an event handler for SelectedIndexChanged:

```
    Private Sub cmbStatus_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbStatus.SelectedIndexChanged
        DoAnnoyingStuff()
        '....
    End sub
```

Elsewhere in my form, I have a function that does this (after some user interaction):

```
Sub RefreshStatus()
    Dim sel As Int32 = GetNewStatus()
    cmbStatus.SelectedIndex = sel   '<-- fires a SelectedIndexChanged event that I don't need
End Sub
```

What I want to do in RefreshStatus() is to change the selection shown in the combobox, but not execute DoAnnoyingStuff().  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually manage the event, enabling and disabling the handler with:

```
AddHandler cmbStatus.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf cmbStatus_SelIndexChg
RemoveHandler cmbStatus.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf cmbStatus_SelIndexChg
```

And as said, you can use a flag:

```
Dim bRefreshStatus As Boolean = False

Private Sub cmbStatus_SelIndexChg(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbStatus.SelectedIndexChanged
    If Not bRefreshStatus Then DoAnnoyingStuff()
End Sub

Sub RefreshStatus()
    Dim sel As Int32 = GetNewStatus()
    bRefreshStatus = True
    cmbStatus.SelectedIndex = sel
    bRefreshStatus = False
End Sub
```

Comment: accepted for AddHandler/RemoveHandler.  Good to learn something new :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a flag. So you would have a private class field called _inChange As Boolean then set the field to true at the start of RefreshStatus, and false at the end. In cmbStatus_SelectedIndexChanged you check if _inChange is true. If it is you just exit. If false you continue and do AnnoyingStuff.

Comment: also a good solution, but I prefer AddHandler/RemoveHandler since I wouldn't need to maintain an extra variable for the event. Thanks though!